# How to preserve spaces in array elements when assigning values with "declare"?

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, scripting

I would like to assign a list of strings to an array. These strings contain significant trailing spaces which I would like to preserve. As shown below, spaces are preserved when I assign the array elements individually. But when I assign the array elements using the "declare" command, the spaces are lost. An awkward solution is to escape each space using "\ ". Is there a better way, or some syntax magic that I am missing?

Code:

```
echo "This does what I want:"
array1[0]="foo   "
array1[1]="bar   "

for element in "${array1[@]}"
do
  echo "${element}x"
done

echo "This makes me sad:"
declare -a array2=("foo   " "bar   ")

for element in "${array2[@]}"
do
  echo "${element}x"
done

echo "This too:"
declare -a array3=('foo   ' 'bar   ')

for element in "${array3[@]}"
do
  echo "${element}x"
done

echo "An awkward solution:"
declare -a array4=("foo\ \ \ " "bar\ \ \ ")

for element in "${array4[@]}"
do
  echo "${element}x"
done
```

Output:

```
This does what I want:
foo   x
bar   x
This makes me sad:
foox
barx
This too:
foox
barx
An awkward solution:
foo   x
bar   x
```

Comment: It works correctly for me.

Comment: ideone.com demo: http://ideone.com/PKiioG

Comment: When I use your "awkward" solution, I see all the backslashes in the output.

Comment: Yes, I looked at your demo. I have an older version of bash (GNU bash, version 2.05b.0(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)). Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: Maybe. It works for me on OS X (3.2.57(1)-release) and Debian (4.2.37(1)-release)

Comment: Yes, it must be a bash version issue. I found the newest bash available to me (GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)) and I was able to duplicate your results there. But I have to run this on the server where it is now, so maybe my awkward workaround is the best I can do.

Comment: Probably. It sounds like a bug in the old version that has been fixed. You've found a workaround for the bug, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My testing matches the comments: this is a bug in much older versions of bash, fixed somewhere between versions 2.05b.0 and 3.2.57. But even in the old version, it appears to work if you separate the declaration from the assignment, or just let the declaration as an array be implicit:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
2.05b.0(1)-release
$ declare -a array1=('foo   ' 'bar   ')    # This triggers the bug
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${array1[@]}"
"foo"
"bar"
$ declare -a array2
$ array2=('foo   ' 'bar   ')    # Separate declaration - this works
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${array2[@]}"
"foo   "
"bar   "
$ array3=('foo   ' 'bar   ')    # Implicit declaration - also works
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${array3[@]}"
"foo   "
"bar   "
```

Comment: You are correct. Somewhere I picked up the idea that I needed to "declare" the array. But the implicit declaration works fine and avoids the old bash bug.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener You do have to declare associative arrays (with `declare -A`), but they're a bash version 4 thing anyway...